# Vagrant Waiting For Domain To Get An IP Address

Tags: vagrant

First, apologies: I'm a newbie.

I've created a very basic Vagrantfile by running Vagrant init. I only made a few changes:

```
config.vm.box = "generic/fedora28"
config.vm.box_version = "1.8.32"
config.vm.provider "libvirt" do |lv|
    lv.memory = "4096"
end
```

(There are also a few items in my `config.vm.provision` section).

After running vagrant up , the process gets stuck at

```
==> default: Waiting for domain to get an IP address...
```

I'm running this off a Fedora 27 box, which uses version 2.0.2 of the Vagrant package (even though current is 2.1.5).

I've tried adding this line:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.101"
```

but it had no effect.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you can always run `vagrant up --debug` and review if you have more information about the error

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271741/vagrant-up-times-out-at-waiting-for-domain-to-get-an-ip-address/57344757 The problem may be related to `iptables`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Vagrant File that spins up 4 VMs, of image generic/ubuntu2004 on libvirt kvm, to make a k3s cluster that's accessible on the LAN. (multipass + k3s is only accessible via localhost b/c it doesn't allow easy bridging.)

I ran both of these commands > 50 times

```
sudo vagrant destroy --force --parallel
sudo vagrant up
```

On the ~51'st time, I noticed vagrant up got stuck on "Waiting for domain to get an IP address..."

What fixed it for me was sudo reboot. You know the classic have you tried unplugging it and plugging it back in?

Something else to try (I rebooted before trying it)
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1283989